# Extract string before dots to a new file

Tags: text-processing

What command is needed to extract a value before dots from the file which has a number of entries and save it in a new file

I have tried the following command:

```
$ filename | cut -d"." -f1 |rev >> exegy
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Give some sample data of input / expected output. Is quite unclear what you want to do and the command you tried looks as a non valid command.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cut -d '.' -f 1 <input >output
```

That should divide each line in the file `input` into dot-separated fields and output only the first of these fields to the file `output`.

It is unclear what your command

```
$filename|cut -d"." -f1 |rev >> exegy
```

means.

Is `$` the prompt or is it part of `$filename`? In either case, you need to get at the contents of the file, not the name of it.

A modified version of your command line:

```
$ cat filename | cut -d"." -f1 | rev >>exegy
```

... but the `cat` isn't needed if you say `cut ... <filename`, as in my suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

With awk:

```
awk -F'.' '{print $1}' filename
```